# Why does this code doesn't print anything in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, range

```
for i in range(0, 10, -1):
    print(i)
```

According to my intuition this code piece should print `0` once and then the condition of range should fail resulting in the breakage of loop, but to my surprise this doesn't print anything.

Comment: You can correct your intuition by reading the [`range` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range). If the `step` is negative, `range` will yield integers until they are lower than the `stop` value.

Answer (score 3):

This is documented under [Ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and `r[i] > stop`.

A range object will be empty if `r[0]` does not meet the value constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not possible to count *down* from 0 to 10, the range will end immediately. range() doesn't work with a negative step size if you're counting  from a lower number to a higher number, so it won't enter the loop- it's just part of it's functionality.

Edit: I believe it technically ends because, since it's counting down (-1), it should end when it gets to 10 or lower. Since it starts already lower than 10, it's already past it's stopping point, so it ends on the first check.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prints because the step is negative. There is no number before 0 in the range 0 to 10, so when it reaches -1 on the first step the loop ends before the action can be taken.